# How to estimate $\alpha$ given a discrete sequence $a(n) = n^{\alpha}+ n^{1-\alpha}+b$.

Tags: numerical-methods

I have a data sequence of length $10^6$ which I know it can be approximately modeled as $a(n) = n^{\alpha}+ n^{1-\alpha}+b$ ($b$ is an unknown constant, $0<\alpha <1$). But how to estimate $\alpha$ here?

**Update:**

Sorry, I made some mistakes above. I sincerely apologize for the mistakes. I revise the problem and explain my concerns more in this update.

The data sequence is generated from simulations of one algorithm. It should have the order $O(n^{\max{(\alpha, 1-\alpha)}})$. I know it can be approximately modeled as $a(n) = b_1n^{\alpha}+ b_2n^{1-\alpha}+b_3$ ($b_1,b_2,b_3$ are unknown constants) when $n$ is suffciently large.

I only care about the order $\max{(\alpha, 1-\alpha)}$ to justify the performance of the algorithm.

I have tried using $\frac{1}{t_1-t_0}\sum_{t=t_0+1}^{t_1}\log_2 \frac{a(2t)}{a(t)}$. The problem is the graph I got does not get the minimum at $\alpha = 0.5$. How to eliminate the numerical errors?

Here's [a link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2861036/how-to-estimate-the-order-max-alpha-1-alpha) of the new post of the problem.

[image]

Comment: You can consider $0<\alpha<\frac12$.

Comment: Is the data noisy or smooth ? Do the initial terms match the model ?

Comment: What are you after, an estimate of the asymptotic behavior or just a best fit to the million points ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we look at the problem as a regression, you have $p$ data points $(n_i,a_i)$ and you want to adjust the model
$$a=n^{\alpha}+n^{1-\alpha}+b$$ In the least square sense, you need to minimize
$$SSQ=\sum_{i=1}^p \left(n_i^{\alpha}+n_i^{1-\alpha}+b -a_i\right)^2$$ Computing the partial derivatives,we have
$$\frac{\partial SSQ}{\partial b}=2\sum_{i=1}^p \left(n_i^{\alpha}+n_i^{1-\alpha}+b -a_i\right)=0\tag 1$$
$$\frac{\partial SSQ}{\partial a}=2\sum_{i=1}^p \left(n_i^{\alpha}+n_i^{1-\alpha}+b -a_i\right)\left(n_i^{\alpha}-n_i^{1-\alpha}\right)\log(n_i)=0 \tag 2$$ which is hard to solve.

However, from $(1)$, you can get $b$ as a function of $\alpha$
$$b(\alpha)=-\frac 1p \sum_{i=1}^p \left(n_i^{\alpha}+n_i^{1-\alpha} -a_i\right)$$ and then $(2)$ is "just" an equation in $\alpha$.

The simplest would be to plot equation $(2)$ for $0 \leq \alpha \leq 0.5$ and see where it does cancels. Zoom more and more to have more accurate results; when your accuracy has been reached, recompute $b$.

All of that can be done using Excel.

**Edit**

For illustration purposes, let us use the following data set
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 i & n_i & a_{n_i} \\
 1 & 10 & 10 \\
 2 & 20 & 14 \\
 3 & 30 & 16 \\
 4 & 40 & 19 \\
 5 & 50 & 21 \\
 6 & 60 & 23 \\
 7 & 70 & 25 \\
 8 & 80 & 26 \\
 9 & 90 & 28 \\
 10 & 100 & 30
\end{array}
\right)$$ A first run, using $\Delta \alpha=0.05$ would give
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \alpha & (2) \\
 0.05 & -36241.2 \\
 0.10 & -19913.1 \\
 0.15 & -10372.8 \\
 0.20 & -4943.28 \\
 0.25 & -1981.30 \\
 0.30 & -483.658 \\
 0.35 & 158.953 
\end{array}
\right)$$ So, the solution is between $0.30$ and $0.35$. Repeat  using $\Delta \alpha=0.005$ to get
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \alpha & (2) \\
 0.315 & -221.502 \\
 0.320 & -148.821 \\
 0.325 & -82.8318 \\
 0.330 & -23.1689 \\
 0.335 & 30.5170 
\end{array}
\right)$$
So, the solution is between $0.330$ and $0.335$. Repeat  using $\Delta \alpha=0.0005$ to get
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
\alpha & (2) \\
 0.3305 & -17.537 \\
 0.3310 & -11.9644 \\
 0.3315 & -6.45098 \\
 0.3320 & -0.996267 \\
 0.3325 & 4.40004 
\end{array}
\right)$$ You will finish with $\alpha=0.332092$ to which correspond $b=3.54869$.

**Update**

If the model is instead
$$a=b_1\,n^{\alpha}+b_2\,n^{1-\alpha}+b_3$$ consider that $\alpha$ is fixed at a given value. For this value, define two parameters $x_i=n_i^ \alpha$, $y_i=n_i^{1-\alpha}$ and so, you face, for a given  $\alpha$ a linear regression
$$a=b_1\,x+b_2\,y+b_3$$ which is easy to solve using matrix calculation or simpler the normal equations 
$$\sum_{i=1}^p a_i=b_1 \sum_{i=1}^p x_i+b_2 \sum_{i=1}^p y_i+b_3\,p$$
$$\sum_{i=1}^p a_ix_i=b_1 \sum_{i=1}^p x_i^2+b_2 \sum_{i=1}^p x_iy_i+b_3\sum_{i=1}^p x_i$$
$$\sum_{i=1}^p a_iy_i=b_1 \sum_{i=1}^p x_iy_i+b_2 \sum_{i=1}^p y_i^2+b_3\sum_{i=1}^p y_i$$  or just multilinear regression.

The resulting parameters are $b_1(\alpha), b_2(\alpha), b_3(\alpha)$ and now consider
$$SSQ(\alpha)=\sum_{i=1}^p \left(b_1(\alpha)\,n_i^{\alpha}+b_2(\alpha)\,n_i^{1-\alpha}+b_3(\alpha) -a_i\right)^2$$ which needs to be minimized with respect to $\alpha$. As before, plot to locate more or less the minimum and zoom more and more until you reach the desired accuracy.

For example, considering the data set
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 i & n_i & a_{n_i} \\
 1 & 10 & 254 \\
 2 & 20 & 357 \\
 3 & 30 & 442 \\
 4 & 40 & 516 \\
 5 & 50 & 584 \\
 6 & 60 & 646 \\
 7 & 70 & 705 \\
 8 & 80 & 761 \\
 9 & 90 & 814 \\
 10 & 100 & 865 \\
 11 & 110 & 914 \\
 12 & 120 & 961 \\
 13 & 130 & 1007 \\
 14 & 140 & 1052 \\
 15 & 150 & 1096
\end{array}
\right)$$ we should have
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
\alpha & SSQ(\alpha) \\
 0.0 & 13251.5 \\
 0.1 & 126.579 \\
 0.2 & 33.3071 \\
 0.3 & 3.82528 \\
 0.4 & 1.38533 \\
 0.5 & 1745.69
\end{array}
\right)$$ Continue zooming in the area of the minimum and finixh with
$$a=10.3547 \,n^{0.363391}+40.1755\, n^{0.636609}+55.9928$$ which will give as final results
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
i & n_i & a_{n_i} & \text{predicted} \\
 1 & 10 & 254 & 253.908 \\
 2 & 20 & 357 & 357.274 \\
 3 & 30 & 442 & 441.825 \\
 4 & 40 & 516 & 516.136 \\
 5 & 50 & 584 & 583.675 \\
 6 & 60 & 646 & 646.276 \\
 7 & 70 & 705 & 705.055 \\
 8 & 80 & 761 & 760.751 \\
 9 & 90 & 814 & 813.890 \\
 10 & 100 & 865 & 864.856 \\
 11 & 110 & 914 & 913.946 \\
 12 & 120 & 961 & 961.392 \\
 13 & 130 & 1007 & 1007.38 \\
 14 & 140 & 1052 & 1052.06 \\
 15 & 150 & 1096 & 1095.57
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: This answer gives me the basic idea of how to do the estimation here, especially the zoom operation. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than a two-parameter least-squares, you might note that your formula implies
$$a_{i+1}-a_i = n_{i+1}^\alpha - n_i^\alpha + n_{i+1}^{1-\alpha} - n_i^{1-\alpha}$$
Find the $\alpha$ that minimizes the sum of squared errors here, then for $b$ take the average of $a_i - (n_i^\alpha + n_i^{1-\alpha})$.

Comment: For sure ! Much simpler than my junk !

Comment: If I am right, $n_i=i$, there is no need to index.

Comment: @YvesDaoust. Not necessary since you can use, say, $n=10,20,30,\cdots$.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: right, but then the formula must be with $a_{n_i}$.

Comment: Many thanks. I have tried your answer. I thought the data can be approximately modeled as $a(n) = n^{\alpha}+ n^{1-\alpha}+b$. Actually, I have $5$ sequences, each should be modeled with $\alpha = 1/1.9,1/2.0, 1/2.1, 1/2.2, 1/2.5$ respectively. However, the strange thing is the partial derivative of the squared errors achieves $0$ at $\alpha = 0.5$ for all sequences. I'm still trying to figure out what happens in the data.

Answer (score 2):

If this helps:

If $a_0$ or $a_1-2$ are available and give reasonable estimates of $b$, for large $n$ we have

$$\frac{a_n-\hat b}{\sqrt n}\sim n^{\alpha-1/2}+n^{1/2-\alpha}=2\cosh\left(\left(\frac12-\alpha\right)\log n\right)$$

and

$$\alpha\sim\frac12-\dfrac{\text{arcosh}\dfrac{a_n-\hat b}{2\sqrt n}}{\log n}.$$

This can be used f.i. as a starting value of an iterative method.

Comment: This seems to be a quite good idea, for sure !

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Data is noisy. The initial terms do not match the model. My concern is just to estimate the asymptotic behavior. The data should be $O(n^{\max{(\alpha,1-\alpha)}})$. I want to get the order of the sequence, i.e. $\max{(\alpha,1-\alpha)}$.

Comment: @JimmyKang: why do you add a constant term ?

Comment: I revised the problem just now. Sorry for the confusion caused.